# React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'charAt')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to capitalize the first letter of the mobile-navigation-title in the component render using a function declared after the useEffect Hook, called capitalizeFirstLetter(string). I get the data from redux (property.category) and dispatch it in the component without any issues when I don't use the function. However, when I use the function with the data {capitalizeFirstLetter(property.category)} I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'charAt'), from the  console

Can't seem to find the issue. The string is there, why is it undefined

```
const PropertyScreen = () => {

  const params = useParams()
  console.log(params.id)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const propertyDetails = useSelector(state => state.propertyDetails)
  const { loading, property, error } = propertyDetails

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listPropertyDetails(params.id))
  }, [dispatch, params.id])

  function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="property-screen">

      <div className="mobile-navigation">
        <Link to={'#'} className='mobile-navigation-title'> {capitalizeFirstLetter(property.category)} </Link>
        <div className='navigation-icons'>
          <IconedButton icon={'faSearch'} />
          <IconedButton icon={'faHome'} link={'/'} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PropertyScreen
```

Comment: `property.category` is null or undefined, hence `string` argument is null or undefined. Change the return to `return string && string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);` instead :) The reason here is that you will have a first render, where the `useEffect` call hasn't completed yet, therefore your state isn't set yet

Comment: Wow thanks a lot this fixed the problem. Looking at the console I knew something was wrong during the first render. but I didn't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

It's giving the error because propertyDetails most likely didn't finish loading on the first render.

You have a bunch of strategies to handle this, but you need to conditional render either the string or the whole component.

For example:

```js
  return (
    <div className="property-screen">

      <div className="mobile-navigation">
        <Link to={'#'} className='mobile-navigation-title'> {(loading)? "loading category..." : capitalizeFirstLetter(property.category)} </Link>
        <div className='navigation-icons'>
          <IconedButton icon={'faSearch'} />
          <IconedButton icon={'faHome'} link={'/'} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```